# Scrolling & Selecting of JList in undecorated frame doesn't work properly

Tags: java, jframe, jlist

I have this strange behavior, look at the following code (or try it out yourself):

```
public class JListProblem
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList Problem");
        frame.setSize( 300, 500);

        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();

        DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
        {
            dlm.addElement( i);
        }

        JList list = new JList(dlm );
        sp.setViewportView( list );
        frame.add( sp );
        frame.setUndecorated( true );
        frame.setBackground( new Color( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) );
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
}
```

Here's my problem:
When you try to scroll, it does not scroll "smoothly" (sorry, I don't know the correct word for this).
Try selecting an entry after scrolling: After you clicked, another entry is selected.

How can I correct this behavior?

When you decrease the amount of entries (change the value of maximum i to 1000 for example), everything is working fine.

Comment: do you have a problem while scrolling using wheel ??

Comment: Yes, this behavior only occurs with the mousewheel. Scrolling with the arrow-keys work properly.

Comment: yeap scrolling means scrolling your JScrollPane not the contents of your list, so use arrow-keys

Comment: Okay, but I if have a huge amount of entries, scrolling with arrow-keys is no solution. Is there a reason of this behavior when using the mousewheel?

Comment: Can it also be because of the transparent background (try Color.BLACK) instead?